# How to read a bit value from a DB and set the value as a Boolean session variable if not null

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I set a bit DB value that's being read from a DB as a Boolean session variable that will be passed from page 1 to page 2. On page 2 I need to verify that the variable is not null before reading its value. The column "Administrator" is a bit type.

page1.aspx:

```
bool IsAdmin = (bool)reader["Administrator"]; // getting Specified cast is not valid here if null
if (IsAdmin)
{
     Session["IsAdministrator"] = true;
}
else
{
    Session["IsAdministrator"] = false;
}
```

page2.aspx:

```
//This is how I would check that the variable is not null if it were a string, how do I check the same for a Boolean?
Boolean isAdmin;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["IsAdministrator"] as string))
{
    isAdmin = (bool)(Session["IsAdministrator"]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

page1.aspx:

```cs
/* if reader["Administrator"] is null, assign false to IsAdmin, alternatively you could throw 
and exception if you are not ok with setting false if the field is NULL on the db */
bool IsAdmin = reader["Administrator"] as bool? ?? false;
if (IsAdmin)
{
     Session["IsAdministrator"] = true;
}
else
{
    Session["IsAdministrator"] = false;
}
```

page2.aspx:

```cs
// You could simplify
Boolean isAdmin = Session["IsAdministrator"] as Boolean? ?? false;
```